# sort rss.xml by pubdate

Tags: php, xml

Is there a way I can sort this RSSfeed by `pubDate` in descending order? 
I tried sort and some other stuff but I can't get it to work. I want to show the 5 last modified pages.

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('../../rssfeed.xml');
$feed = array();

foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array(
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;

for ($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="' . $link . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $title . '</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on ' . $date . '</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>' . $description . '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I suspect you had a lot of potential duplicate questions while composing this question, all having some variant of `usort()` as an answer? Well, guess what? `usort` _is_ your friend. If you have trouble using it, try to share your best effort using that in the question and we'll have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) on your feed array. Using `strtotime()` on `$item['data']` as items' compare value should get you set:

```
function compareItems($a,$b) {
    $a=strtotime($a['date']);
    $b=strtotime($b['date']);

    if($a==$b)
        return 0;
    elseif($a < $b)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Now everything left to do is to run `usort($feed,'compareItems');`

Comment: i try to use what u say, but i dont understand how i must put that code together. How can i use usort for $item[date]. Sorry but i am fairly new to xml parsing

Comment: It's got little to do with XML sorting.

Comment: i get this error: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: u are a hero, i learned alot from this code :) I can use this for many other functions thx!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that uses array_multisort to sort the times in the RSS feed. Notice the changes to the $item array that is being made.

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('../../rssfeed.xml');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array (
            'title' => htmlspecialchars_decode($node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue),
            'description' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'time' => strtotime($node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue),
            );
    $x++;
    $times[$x] = $item['time'];
    $items[$x] = $item;
}

array_multisort($times, SORT_DESC, $items);
$items = array_slice( $items, 5 );

foreach($items as $item) {
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($item['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$item['link'].'" title="'.$item['title'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($item['title']).'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$item['description'].'</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more compact version of DaSourcerer's answer using [Anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and the Spaceship [operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (Requires PHP7):

```
usort($feed, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) <=> strtotime($b['date']);
});
```

Of if you want them sorted with the newest first just swap $a and $b within the function:

```
usort($feed, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($b['date']) <=> strtotime($a['date']);
});
```